# fetch to table group by and save

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to ask your help. I want to display data to table and group by ID that looks like this in laravel 5.

Article 1: good article
Comments: 1 - i love this article
          2 - good one

Article 2: read this
Comments: 3 - waiting for more

here's my API to fetch to my table

```
 $.get('/dev/api/getPODetails?id=' + id, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(index, getPODetails){
    $('table.table tbody').append('<tr><td>PO#'+getPODetails.id+'</td><br><td>'+getPODetails.itemdesc+'</td><td>'+getPODetails.ordered+'</td></tr>');
            })
        });
```

and my controller

public function getPODetails(){

```
$supplierid = Input::get('id');
        $getSupplierDetails = DB::table('purchase_headers')
                                ->where('purchase_headers.partner_id',$supplierid)
                                ->leftJoin('purchase_details', 'purchase_headers.id', '=', 'purchase_details.po_no_id' )
                                ->leftJoin('items', 'purchase_details.item_id', '=', 'items.id' )
                            ->select('items.description as itemdesc', 'purchase_details.qoh as ordered', 'purchase_headers.id as id')
                            ->groupBy('purchase_details.id')
                            ->get();
    return Response::json($getSupplierDetails, 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

And I want to save all the details from the table.

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking, could you try to re-word the question?

Comment: I would like to fetch the data which is by group.  For example header table have PO#1 and the sub table has 2 PO#1 contains 2 items. I want to display it on the table that looks like this                                      PO#1: 
1 - i love this article
 2 - good one

PO#2: 
 3 - waiting for more

Comment: my current would be look like this